# making sticky whatsapp icon on left side for my website

Tags: html, css

I have an website and wanted to add a whatsapp icon to the left side of my screen as shown in the image below: [image]

Down below the `html` code is for adding the whatsapp icon

```
<a  class="whats-app" href="#" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-whatsapp my-float"></i>
</a>
```

and this is the `css` styling I have used

```
.whats-app {
    position: fixed;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    bottom: 40px;
    right: 15px;
    background-color: #25d366;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
    z-index: 100;
}

.my-float {
    margin-top: 16px;
}
```

From the above `css` and `html` this is the outcome: [image: outcome]. In `css` I changed `left:15px` from `right:15px` but still the second image.

Can I know where it went wrong?

Though I have commented the above `css` then also it is showing the whats app icon and `css` properties in the console

Comment: What is the issue with how it is now? Do you want it aligned with the arrow button?

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz example ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this CSS.

```
.whats-app {
    position: fixed;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 40px;
    background-color: #25d366;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    box-shadow: 3px 4px 3px #999;
    left: 15px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.my-float {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: i tried adding `left: 15px;` but it is not changing in the console it is showing the first css properties only

Comment: @KrupalPanchal Try clearing cache and do hard reload.

Comment: @Hemavathi If you don't write `right` property then it will automatically shift to left.

Comment: Straight and to the point. Also if you remove `left: 15px;` and change it to `right: 15px;` it will be stuck to the right.

Answer (score 1):

You needs to add `left: 0` or `left: (pixels you want)` in `.whats-app` css. and needs to remove `right: 15px` from css

Try this hope it will help you.

```css
.whats-app {
    position: fixed;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    bottom: 40px;
    background-color: #25d366;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 15px;
}

.my-float {
    margin-top: 16px;
}
```

```html
<a  class="whats-app" href="#" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-whatsapp my-float"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: if you add left value before right value.. its shows right only.. so you should unset right value

Comment: @Ranjithv Then what is the issue? as i already removed `right: 15px`.

Answer (score 1):

try this.. here i unset the right value

**css**

```
.whats-app {
position: fixed;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
bottom: 40px;
left:0;
right:unset;
background-color: #25d366;
color: #FFF;
border-radius: 50px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 30px;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
z-index: 100;
}

.my-float {
    margin-top: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the below code.

```css
 .icon-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
} 

.icon-bar a {
  display: block;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #448edd;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.whatsapp {
  background: #53d365;
  color: #448edd;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="icon-bar">
  <a href="#" class="whatsapp"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i></a> 
</div>
```